# Make an automatic <br>?

Tags: php, html

So I'm trying to create to create a foruming site, but when a thread is selected, it doesn't enter how the user put it. Example:
This would be what the user put:

`Example
Here`

But the website would output it as:

`Example Here`

It just jams it all together.
Any solutions? Thanks.
Code:
`echo "<h2>".htmlspecialchars($thread['desc'], ENT_QUOTES)."</h2>";`

Read the answers to see how this was solved!

Comment: Any code? Please post MCVE at least

Comment: Check out php's: [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: @AleksandarĐokić Updated it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson is htmlspecialchars() compatible with that? Example: nl2br(htmlspecialchars($thread['desc'], ENT_QUOTES))

Comment: Sure, why not? A new line shouldn't be considered a special char, as far as I know. Just try it. :)

Comment: `nl2br()` basicly just meas: New line to line break. A new line isn't a special character so `htmlspecialchars()` won't affect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the answer**
So, nl2br() plays a great role with this.
I managed to come up with

```
<?
echo "<h2>".nl2br(htmlspecialchars($thread['desc'], ENT_QUOTES))."<h2>";
?>
```

Thanks to @MagnusEriksson for mentioning nl2br().

Comment: You should mark it as resolved.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It says that I can't do it, I have to wait 2 days